# How to set mainClassName if my application is created with gradle?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

My project is created with grails, now i am trying to get the mainClassName in the build.gradle but it keep run out into error as below:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.github.ManifestClasspath" version "0.1.0-RELEASE"
}
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'org.gradle.abc.Main'

Could not find or load main class org.gradle.abc.Main
```

My main class is in the grails-app -> init -> abc -> Application

below is my mainClassFile

```
package abc

import grails.boot.GrailsApp
import grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
//import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling

@CompileStatic
//@EnableScheduling
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }
}
```

I need to get the MainClassName in order to solve the PathingJar Problems in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main class' FQN is `abc.Application` (`package abc;`) and not `org.gradle.abc.Main`

Comment: I also tried this one before, but run up this error
Could not find or load main class abc.Application

Comment: @WilliamNg do you need the `@CompileStatic`? Can you try removing it?

Comment: hmmm, i don't think it was because of compileStatic, i tried to remove it but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

The main class in grails should be  set in springBoot construction of build.gradle:

```
 springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'abc.Application'
}
```